# Angularjs- showing skeleton while loading data

Tags: angularjs

Is there anyway to show skeleton (empty boxes- if I need to load some images and text from background using services) while loading data from api services so that user get a feeling something is happening over instead of showing empty page and dump data once ready.

Comment: I am using ng-repeat with infinite loading .. structure with one left div for image and right div for text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple ng-show, and a loaded variable.

ie

```
<div ng-show="Controller.loaded"></div>

$scope.loaded = false;
$http.get(...)
    .then(...{
        $scope.loaded = true;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will not show any skeleton view as I expect, until the loaded is true div will not be visible..but before the data populate I need to show empty boxes

Comment: @user3622819 the same process works - show your data boxes when loaded is true, and display a placeholder box when loaded is false.

Comment: so what you suggested is having one more div with empty styles, enable it when loaded is false and switch to data mode on loaded is true? Hmm.. it makes sense.. but if I need to show this in ng-repeat need to check ..I am using infinity loading

Answer (score -1):

you need [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

there is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/r4yMfpJ1b4r5SJmIeN1k?p=preview) however it's too fast to be noticed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-cloak-production</title>    
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
<div id="template2">{{ 'world' }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

try it on your project and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks Sombriks, but ng-cloak will just hide Angular data till angular is bootstrap, but our requirement is to show some structure so that user may get feeling something is loading..So he can wait